# Remove indent after typing 'Enter' in numbered list

Tags: vim

When I start a numbered list, everything seems to be going well; when lines wrap, they are indented an appropriate amount so that they start in the same column as the first line (minus the digit, period, and space).

But when I'm done with my first list item and hit 'Enter', I expect the next line *not* to continue this indentation, because I'm trying to start a new list item. Instead, it keeps the indent, and without manually deleting the indent each time I start a new line, things get a little out of hand.

```
$ vim -u NONE -N
```

-

```
:set textwidth=20
:set formatoptions=want
:set autoindent
```

-

```
1. this is a list
   item it is the
   only list item so
   far
   2. this is
      another list
      item it is the
      second one
      3. here is yet
         another
         list item
         4. another
            list
            item
            goes
            here
            5. yet
               another
```

Is there any way I can prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

There's not an automatic way, because Vim has no way of knowing you're done with the current entry and want to move on to a new one.

But, in insert mode, you can use <kbd><C-D></kbd> to DEindent a line after you've started it, without moving the cursor or leaving insert mode.

Comment: I think that the main problem is that Vim does not know that you are inside a list item. `formatlistpat` is used only for deciding what the indent of second line should be, then the indent is only preserved via `autoindent`. Try `:setl noautoindent` and try to compose a list.